# Unable to increase start time of Websphere server

Tags: java, websphere

In websphere server,if I am increasing time beyond 1800 , Its value again changing to 300 when I am unfocusing on textbox , I am unable to increase beyond 1800.

Comment: Is this a setting on the Websphere console? Which setting are you referring to?

Comment: Impossible to understand what the problem is based on the limited information provided.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird! Because I tried to increase it to 2800 and it works fine while saving. It is not reverting it to 300. Try deleting the server and recreate a server. May be this would help.